# PowerQuery: Find first and last entry in group

Tags: powerquery

I have a dataset that has one or more rows per individual person, arranged chronologically from earliest to latest. Each row has a metric associated with that person. I want to be able to find the difference between the metric in the earliest and latest observation by person, and divide it by the time difference between the earliest and latest entry. I'm a PowerQuery newbie, how would I go about this?

Comment: Provide sample input data ( as text not an image) and  sample desired output clearly explaining how you go from one to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have a table similar to this:

| Person | DateTime | Metric |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-10-01 13:23:46 | 50 |
| A | 2023-10-09 17:14:04 | 10 |
| A | 2023-10-11 23:12:08 | 15 |
| A | 2023-10-12 01:01:01 | 51 |
| B | 2023-10-22 13:42:42 | 40 |
| B | 2023-10-24 22:12:50 | 45 |
| B | 2023-10-29 07:17:51 | 48 |
| C | 2023-11-05 07:54:20 | 30 |
| C | 2023-11-07 20:08:05 | 20 |
| D | 2023-11-14 04:46:58 | 10 |

Follow these steps:

1. Right-click on the `Person` header and select `Group By...`
   In the pop-up window, enter `PersonRows` in the `New column name`, set `Operation` to `All Rows`. Then click `OK`.
2. Now add a Custom Column with:

```
let
  metricDiff = List.Last([PersonRows][Metric]) - List.First([PersonRows][Metric]),
  timeDiff = List.Last([PersonRows][DateTime]) - List.First([PersonRows][DateTime]),
  calc = metricDiff / Duration.TotalMinutes(timeDiff),
  result = if Number.IsNaN(calc) then null else calc
in
  result
```

For `calc`, change `Duration.TotalMinutes` to `Duration.TotalDays`, `Duration.TotalHours`, or `Duration.TotalSeconds` - as per your needs.

3. Finally, either remove the `PersonRows` column or expand it (via the double split arrows in the header) - depending on your needs.

Hope this has helped.

Full query below, for reference:

```
let
  Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("ZdBLCsMwDATQqwivG5iRpSbRrp9bhNz/GpVMKaEGrYZn63Mc7dFuTaF9IRZQ2EN72D1TRztvf2AXrkELWKacASn5nBrYCvgMVMAYVS04wPMCVGsG06xMDTMwUa0WOV8Cn8EuyCHX8Gph2wCvH+ACL+AWWj90zGAVRa4Q8JEO8L4AmsDySuHb9w7nBw==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Person = _t, DateTime = _t, Metric = _t]),
  #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Person", type text}, {"DateTime", type datetime}, {"Metric", Int64.Type}}),
  #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Person"}, {{"PersonRows", each _, type table [Person=nullable text, DateTime=nullable datetime, Metric=nullable number]}}),
  #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Result", each 
    let
      metricDiff = List.Last([PersonRows][Metric]) - List.First([PersonRows][Metric]),
      timeDiff = List.Last([PersonRows][DateTime]) - List.First([PersonRows][DateTime]),
      calc = metricDiff / Duration.TotalMinutes(timeDiff),
      result = if Number.IsNaN(calc) then null else calc
    in
      result
  )
in
  #"Added Custom"
```